# TypeScript Enum cannot be assigned to type Enum.Value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this Enum:

```
export enum EntityTypes {
  VALUE = 'value',
  OTHER = 'other',
}
```

and this type:

```
export type ValueEntity = {
  entityType: EntityTypes.VALUE
}
```

and this func:

`const myFunc = (entity: ValueEntity) => {}`

If I do:

`myFunc({ entityType: EntityTypes.VALUE })`

I get the error: `Type 'EntityTypes' is not assignable to type 'EntityTypes.VALUE'.`

If I do

`myFunc({ entityType: EntityTypes.VALUE as EntityTypes.VALUE })`

it works but that's an ugly workaround...

Comment: no error [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAylQm). Please provide a minimum reproducable example.

Comment: I don't think you need to use EntityTypes.VALUE after as

Comment: Inside the Function constructor you don't need cast type value just tipe, ex: myFunc({entityType: EntityTypes}) then handle data inside the function block. If you want default value then ex: myFunc(entity Type = EntityTypes.VALUE)